# How do I update multiple subform records in a linear fashion from a main form?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a date textbox in the main form that outputs 6 sequential dates (2 week intervals) in a subform. The subform is populated with these dates as part of the main form’s `AfterInsert()` event.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 12 Step 2
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Date (DateDescriptionID, TestDate) "
        strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT " & Me.tbDescriptionID & ", (DateAdd('ww', " & i & ", #" & Me.tbStartDate & "#));"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    Next i
End Sub
```

If the user changes the date textbox in the main form, I would like the subform dates to reflect that change. I tried an `UPDATE` query to replace the existing dates with the new dates, but am having trouble trying to get the primary-foregin keys aligned. I'm only able to replace the existing dates with empty values (null), but am not sure how to correspondingly update the existing dates with the new dates.

```
Private Sub tbStartDate_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_Date "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SET [TestDate] = NULL "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE [DateDescriptionID] = " & Me.DescriptionID & ";"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

**User Enters 05/01/2018**

```
Date           Data
05/15/2018     Apple
05/29/2018     Banana
06/12/2018     Orange
06/26/2018     Strawberry
07/10/2018     Pineapple
07/24/2018     Peach
```

**User Changes Entry to 06/30/2018**

```
Date           Data
07/14/2018     Apple
07/28/2018     Banana
08/11/2018     Orange
08/25/2018     Strawberry
09/08/2018     Pineapple
09/22/2018     Peach
```

Comment: Couldn't you just update the date to the same DateDiff period as the from the original date. Air Code - `NewDateValue = CurrentDateValue + DateDiff("D" ,OldStartDate,NewStartDate)`

Comment: Great suggestion! How would I pass the old start date? Should I use a global variable during the `BeforeUpdate()` event?

Comment: Why not store the intervall, instead of the Dates, or if constant 2 weeks just store the order sequence and compute the date `= DateAdd("ww",2 * countOfFormerElements,StartDate)`

Comment: @Minty I was able to access the control's old value by doing `Me.tbStartDate.OldValue`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher The interval will always be constant at 2 weeks. How do I store the order sequence in an `UPDATE` SQL?

Comment: If the order sequence doesn't change and  table has an ID (Autoincrement) this should be sufficent. Just insert the `Data` in the desired order, then count numer of elements with ID smaller than own. If stquence can change add a number forle that stores the number in sequence that you can update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip all the SQL stuff and use DAO and the *recordsetclone* - much cleaner and faster and with automatic update:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone
    For i = 2 To 12 Step 2
        rs.AddNew
            rs!DateDescriptionID.Value = Me!tbDescriptionID.Value
            rs!TestDate.Value = DateAdd("ww", i, Me!tbStartDate.Value)
        rs.Update
    Next i
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

and:

```
Private Sub tbStartDate_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone

    rs.MoveFirst
    While Not rs.EOF
        i = i + 2
        rs.Edit
           rs!TestDate.Value = DateAdd("ww", i, Me!tbStartDate.Value)
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend        
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right about this being cleaner and faster. I will explore with DAO more in my databases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a correlated subquery but since MS Access only allows updateable queries for `UPDATE` statements, use a `DCount` domain aggregate. Additionally, consider [parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) to cleanly separate SQL code from VBA data values.

Specifically, the `DCount` produces a rank order of *TestDate* column and then multiples each by 14, the desired interval length of days (e.g., 1*14, 2*14, 3*14). No loops are needed for this solution.

**SQL** *(save as a stored Access query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [DescIDParam] Long;
UPDATE tbl_Date t
SET t.[TestDate] = DCount("*", "tbl_Date", "TestDate <= #" & t.[TestDate] & "#") * 14, t.[TestDate])
WHERE t.[DateDescriptionID] = [DescIDParam]
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub tbStartDate_AfterUpdate()
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedUpdateQuery")

    ' BIND VALUE TO PARAMETER
    qdef![DescIDParam] = Me.tbDescriptionID

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I go for SQL:

I assume a table named `tblData` with fields `ID`(PK, Autoincrement) , `Data` (Text) and `Sort`(Long)

```
ID     Data        Sort
1     Apple          3
2     Banana         5
3     Orange         2
4     Strawberry     1
5     Pineapple      4
6     Peach          6
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT Data, DateAdd("ww", 2 * Sort, Forms!ParentForm!txtDate) as ComputedDate FROM tblData Order By Sort;
```

Use this as Recordsource for Subform. If `txtDate`is stored in a table you can join or lookup.
Just one Date stored always up-to-date.